# Unable to stream audio from sound card through vlc over the LAN

Tags: audio-streaming, vlc, soundcard

With reference to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914725/streaming-tv-tuner-card-output-using-vlc

I have founded the issue with it and now i am successfully able to stream the video from the tv tuner card over the LAN using VNC.

But i found that no audio is being streamed with that of the video.

Certain research led me to a conclusion that we can stream the sound card using the vlc .
I followed certain links too which followed how to stream the sound card.I have followed the same steps but i am not able to stream the sound card .

Main link which i have seen regarding this : `http://www.screenr.com/BFH`

Can anyone guide me in right direction to help get me out of this situation.

Please help.All help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i need to enable the Line In of my machine.

Done that and then streamed the sound card using vlc and it worked properly.